# advice on writing sql delete statement

Tags: sql

i'm trying to write a delete statement using sql, based off of certain criteria. i am having trouble with it. here is the criteria.

the program should prompt the user for a ssn and delete that employee from the Employee table (the records from the Technician table and from the Expert table that reference that employee will also be deleted as a result of the ON DELETE CASCADE action)

Comment: Something like this?: `DELETE FROM Employee WHERE SSN = @SSN`

Comment: What's exactly the problem? You want to avoid the effect of `ON DELETE CASCADE` ?

Comment: how to incorporate using on ON DELETE CASCADE

Answer (score 2):

```
DELETE FROM Employees WHERE SSN='508-12-1234'
```

Assuming the Technician and Expert tables have foreign keys set up properly, this should be all you need to do.

Comment: i am using oracle sql developer, is there a way to check if my foreign keys are set up properly?

Comment: I haven't used that tool. Try looking at the Technician and Expert tables. There should be a spot that shows "Keys". There needs to be an entry in there that links the Employee and Technician together (same deal for the Expert table)

Comment: ok, thank you for your help.  i have this for my code. 

EXEC SQL BEGIN DECLARE SECTION;
  char sn[9];
 EXEC SQL END DECLARE SECTION;

 cout << "Enter social security number of employee to be deleted: ";
 cin >> sn;
 
 EXEC SQL DELETE FROM EMPLOYEES WHERE SSN=:sn;
 EXEC SQL COMMIT WORK;

does that look ok?